# How to Restrict iOS Wifi Settings from being Changed?

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, settings

I have iPad Mini 3 with iOS 8. I set the restrictions under Settings > General > Restrictions but some important settings are not covered like WiFi, Proxy and DNS settings.

How can I restrict WiFi settings from being changed to some other values other than mine? I need this for parental controls. If possible how can disable or hide Settings app all together?

Comment: Sorry,AFIK that can not be done. You can disable the WiFi but not lock it down to specific SSID. However the user needs to know others SSID and passwords to connect to them.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible if you setup and install a custom security profile like many businesses do for devices they issue.  Apple makes a Mac app called [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?l=en&mt=12) that I am going to look into.  I will try to remember to post back if I figure it out.

Comment: Apple Configurator 2 (Mac) and iPhone Configuration Utility (Windows, out-dated, not supported)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible under stock iOS 8; there is nothing under General > Restrictions (or anything in the Settings App) that would help.

If it is absolutely critical, you can look into jailbreaking the iPad (which would void any warranty), but doing that is going to extremes to just solve this one issue, haha.

Sorry that this probably isn't what you wanted to hear!